# Any history of changes made during a refactoring in NetBeans 8?

Tags: netbeans

After doing a refactoring in NetBeans 8, is there any way to learn what actions were taken? Is there a log or history tracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right on top of the first line of code should be a button named "source" and right next to it should be a button named "history". After saving your file, any changes are hold here. Hit the history button and you can browse your changes.

If the buttons are not there, go to menu "view/show editor toolbar".